# Implementing a selectable list of items in Meteor 0.8.0 (Blaze)

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Suppose we wanted to implement a selectable list of items where clicking something in the list would highlight the item by adding a `selected` class to it and removing this class from anything else in the list. Meteor 0.8 gives us two equally viable ways to do this:

### 1. The reactive way

```
<template name="dataItem">
    <li class="data-cell {{selected}}">
        {{> dataStuff}}
    </li>
</template>
```

with the following code:

```
Template.dataItem.events =
  "click .data-cell": (e) ->
    Session.set("selectedTweet", @_id)

Template.dataItem.selected = ->
  if Session.equals("selectedTweet", @_id) then "selected" else ""
```

This method was bad prior to Meteor 0.8 because selecting/unselecting caused a re-render of the entire element which made any DOM operations on it get reset.

#### Pros:

- Meteor takes care of all the rendering and there are no logic errors
- Blaze only updates the part of the DOM that changed - no entire template redraws

#### Cons:

- If the list is 500 items long, 500 reactive computations are checked each time something is selected or unselected.

### 2. The pure jQuery way

```
<template name="dataItem">
    <li class="data-cell">
        {{> dataStuff}}
    </li>
</template>
```

with code:

```
Template.dataItem.events =
  "click .data-cell": (e, t) ->
    $(".data-cell").removeClass("selected")
    t.$(".data-cell").addClass("selected")
```

This operation was basically completely impossible prior to Meteor 0.8.

#### Pros:

- Probably the most performance efficient for large lists
- No need to check through a huge number of reactive computations

#### Cons:

- Could be prone to logic errors in more advanced cases.
- Feels like we're going back into the world of jQuery spaghetti.

If you were implementing a list like this, what would you choose? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't know if your con for the first case is correct.  From the docs on [Deps.dependency](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency): 'When you call Session.equals("weather", "sunny"), the current computation is made to depend on an internal Dependency that does not change if the weather goes from, say, "rainy" to "cloudy".'  If you have confirmed the 500 helper calls then it seems like unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @user728291 it doesn't invalidate the 499 other dependencies but it certainly will check them all, which is probably more work than just going through 500 DOM nodes - or is it?

Comment: I think the dependencies are looked up by the value being checked in equals, like `if ( dependency[ sessionKey ][equalsValue] )`. So you should be getting two that invalidate - the old [key][oldValue] and the [key][newValue].

Comment: I agree with you that two invalidate. Still, the entire list will be checked.

Comment: Checking those 499 dependencies is likely to be very fast.  I would build some tests and see if you can reach a number that makes one strategy out perform the other.  My guess is that rendering the entire set itself will become slow before you see any major difference between the two selection strategies.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to solve this would be to not store one session variable to account for the selected item, but instead to store the selection state of all items in the list, each in a separate `Session` variable. Something like this, assuming you have a list over all `_id`s in `allIds`:

```
allIds = ...

Template.dataItem.events =
  "click .data-cell": (e) ->
    allIds.forEach((id) -> Session.set("#{id}-selected", ""))
    Session.set("#{@_id}-selected", "selected")

Template.dataItem.selected = ->
  Session.get("#{@_id}-selected")
```

Of course, this assumes that the `Session.set` with the same value wouldn't invalidate the reactive computation; something off which I'm not sure. If that's the case, then I suppose one could check the value before setting it. Not super satisfied with this solution, but it's another way of tackling the problem.

Comment: So each time something is selected, you are going to set the value of 500 session variables, and cause 500 helper recomputations? I fail to see how this is more efficient in any sense, even if you're going to use `Session.equals()` to check the match. Moreover, it provides a lot of opportunity for logic errors - the approach I suggested only allows **one** item to be selected at a time.